# How to get the value of selected row directly in HTML using ag-grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid

i try to get the the value of number row selected, and print it in HTML using Angularjs, but no issue,
i have the count only when i clic in the grid column header.
The value of " selectedRowsCounter " is 0 in html, when i dosn't clic in the grid header

my code is like

```
var activeButtons = function() {
        var countRowsSelected =    $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows().length;
    $scope.selectedRowsCounter = countRowsSelected;
    console.log($scope.selectedRowsCounter);
    $rootScope.count.selectedRows = countRowsSelected;
};

$scope.gridOptions = {
    rowData: null,
    angularCompileRows: true,
    onSelectionChanged: activeButtons,
}
```

there is a screenshot

[image]

i have open the same subject here
https://github.com/ceolter/ag-grid/issues/1023

Answer (score 0):

i have added this line to activeButtons function and it work fine

```
$scope.gridOptions.api.refreshView();
```

i dont knew if there is a good solution, but that work for now

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be with Angular being unaware of the $scope property change because ag-grid does not tell Angular that it has modified something in the $scope. Although it is difficult to tell if you don't show your view.

You can use `onSelectionChanged` the way you are using it to know how many rows have been selected, but you need to tell Angular that something has changed in its $scope by applying it.

Something like this:

```
var activeButtons = function() {
    var countRowsSelected =    $scope.gridOptions.api.getSelectedRows().length;
    $scope.selectedRowsCounter = countRowsSelected;
    console.log($scope.selectedRowsCounter);
    $rootScope.count.selectedRows = countRowsSelected;
    window.setTimeout(function() {
         this.$scope.$apply();
    });
};
```

That way you can apply the $scope and the html view will reflect the changes.

Comment: thank you for your answer, - timeout in evry change made my code very slow !!

Comment: you can set it to 0. It won't execute immediately but on the next tick. That shouldn't slow things down in a noticeable way. 
`setTimeout(function(){$scope.$apply();}, 0);`

Comment: whats the best between yours method and the refreshVew method of ag-grid, thank you